# What is Splatfest?

Tags: splatoon-2

I've been playing Splatoon 2 and while I was watching Off The Hook, they were saying stuff about something called "Splatfest." I know nothing about it. I have picked my team, but I still don't get what Splatfest is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [**Splatfest**](https://splatoonwiki.org/wiki/Splatfest) is a festival within Splatoon and Splatoon 2.

It's basically an event, where you choose one side or another, then fight against people from the other side.

Participation is rewarded with [**Super Sea Snails**](https://splatoonwiki.org/wiki/Super_Sea_Snail). The amount you receive depends on whether your team won, and how much experience you collected during the festival. The amount ranges from 2 to 24 per Splatfest.

Super Sea Snails are used to increase the number of slots on your [**gear**](https://splatoonwiki.org/wiki/Gear) or reroll all [**abilities**](https://splatoonwiki.org/wiki/Ability) on a specified piece of gear.

The only other way to collect Super Sea Snails is to level up after reaching level 30, with each level up awarding a single Super Sea Snail (for a maximum of 20 in total).